# Modify plot with dots instead of horizontal lines and more granular y axis values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

**Question:**

Using this data and the following code creates a plot showing horizontal lines for the `nlargest` values from the `'# of Trades'` column.

How do we show these `nlargest` values as a dot (is scatter plot the correct terminology?) which is placed at the area the `nlargest` values were observed instead of a horizontal line?

**Data:**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

df = pd.read_csv('for_stack_nums.csv')


axnum = df[['High','Low']].plot()
axnum.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f')) 

for idx, l in df.nlargest(5, '# of Trades').iterrows():
    plt.axhline(y=l['High'], color='r')
    plt.axhline(y=l['Low'], color='b')
    plt.show()
```

[image]

**Desired output:**

A plot showing the existing `df[['High','Low']].plot()` but with the horizontal lines replaced by dots and the y axis values incrementing in steps of .05 instead of .2 as is currently seen. 
If the dot size could be relative to the nlargest value rank this would be nice.  So the biggest value is the biggest dot.

Comment: Scatter is what you're looking for http://matplotlib.org/examples/shapes_and_collections/scatter_demo.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modified Answer based on comment

```
axnum = df[['High','Low']].plot()
axnum.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f')) 
axnum.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(.05))

data = df.nlargest(5, '# of Trades')[['High', 'Low']]
plt.scatter(data.index, data.High, color='r', s=np.linspace(50, 10, 5))
plt.scatter(data.index, data.Low, color='b', s=np.linspace(50, 10, 5))
```

[image]

You need to create a scatter plot. Here is some simple code that will get it done for you.

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

axnum = df[['High','Low']].plot()
axnum.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FormatStrFormatter('%.2f')) 
axnum.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(.05))

x = np.linspace(0, len(df), 10)
for i, (idx, l) in enumerate(df.nlargest(5, '# of Trades').iterrows()):
    plt.scatter(x, y=[l['High']]*len(x), color='r', marker='o', s=(5-i) * 5 + 5)
    plt.scatter(x, y=[l['Low']]*len(x), color='b', marker='o', s=(5-i) * 5 + 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Can the dots be placed at the area the nlargest values were observed at.  So a single dot for each nlargest value at the respective timestamp? Many thanks

Comment: I updated the answer to only plot dots on the point they were observed.